# Doctrine self referencing entity relationship throws error

Tags: doctrine-orm, entity-relationship, self-reference

I have a self referencing entity in Doctrine but I keep getting the following error when I try to persist them:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Category could not be converted to string in vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php on line 165
```

Example:

```
$category1 = new Category();
$category1->setName("Foo");
$category1->setParent( NULL );

$category2 = new Category();
$category2->setName("Bar");
$category2->setParent( $category1 );

$manager->persist( $category1 );
$manager->persist( $category2 );

$manager->flush();
```

My entity looks like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="categories")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, unique=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    protected $children;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName( $name )
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    public function setParent( Category $parent = NULL )
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    public function setChildren( ArrayCollection $children )
    {
        $this->children = $children;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

I have Googled and compared my code to other examples but I can't seem to spot the problem. I'm obviously overlooking something, but what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
protected $parent;
```

But I also recommend you to set *onDelete="SET NULL"* on the parent column, like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
public $parent;
```

I know it's not part of the question, but you are probably going to need this in the near future. If you want the *children* column to give you the categories in a order that the user can choose, you may want to add a integer column named *order* and define *children* like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"order" = "ASC"})
 */
public $children;
```

Comment: Give me +1 (up arrow on left of my answer) if this helped you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for that. This seems to work. Would you be able to explain *why* my version didn't work? Even though I had the syntax a bit different, I'd like to understand where the error came from. I'd up vote twice for the category suggestion if I could. :)

Comment: Hello. I think the only error was in the syntax (you putting nullable in a *column* annotation).